# csv file reading php with commas

Tags: php, csv

I developed one application in PHP.in that users uploads CSV format files.

to read CSV file Cell data i written code like this :

```
$file_pointer = fopen($filename, "r");
if($file_pointer)
{
    $file_read = fread($file_pointer, filesize($filename));
    $file_read=preg_replace('/(\r\n|\n|\r)/', ',', $file_read);

    $exp = explode(',',$file_read);
```

> **//I am getting Data from this Array**

```
}
```

this is working fine but in case in CSV file one cell having like : **Text,Here**

When reading this script i am getting one more index in array....

i need to read as a single indexed data

Comment: It looks like there's some sort of formatting issue with your answer. Besides that, have you tried removing any trailing commas/whitespace, those sometimes can cause problems.

Comment: Why do this? You should use `fgetcsv()`.

Comment: Are there quotes around values which contain commas?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
$yourstuff = fgetcsv($file_pointer, 0, ',', '"');
```